# How setting laravel-websockets url under /admin to protect it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, websocket

Using beyondcode/laravel-websockets packege 
I can modify config option

```
'path' => ‘admin/laravel-websockets’
```

to run it under admin, but how to protected access to it to logged user with admin rights, as in my routes/web.php I have group :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isVerified', 'CheckUserStatus'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
```

**Modified block:**
In file config/websockets.php I added  :

```
'path' => 'admin/laravel-websockets',

'middleware' => [   // to run it under admin, but how to protected access to it to logged user with admin rights, as in my routes/web.php I have group :
    'web',
],

'statistics' => [
```

But it does not help and my admin/laravel-websockets page is not protected.
Have I to add some specific rules to routes/web.php ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your file `config/websockets.php` you can add all the middlewares you want:

```js
'middleware' => [
    'web',
],
```

If you can't find this file you should check the [official documentation](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/getting-started/installation.html) about laravel-websockets.

Comment: Please, look at Modified block

Answer (score 0):

Just make a normal middleware to check if user have admin rights e.g. `isAdmin` and then add it to the array

```
'middleware' => [
    'web',
    'isAdmin'
],
```